# Keyboard doesn't work after upgrade to Debian Wheezy

Tags: keyboard, xserver, debian-wheezy

After upgrade from lenny to wheezy keyboard and mouse don't work in X (keyboard available before it starts). I looked over internet about this issue and found some solutions:

1. remove xorg.conf (http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=62880)
2. update udev and base-files (http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=64927&p=376136#p376136)
3. remove /run directory (http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=64927&p=376136#p376136)
4. reintall xserver and xorg

But, nothing helped me :( Logs of X-server haven't got any messages about keyboard or mouse errors.

Below you can see configuration of my system:

```
krestyaninov@xxx# uname -a
Linux xxx 3.0.0-1-686-pae #1 SMP Sat Aug 27 16:41:03 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux

krestyaninov@xxx# dpkg -l |grep udev
ii  libgudev-1.0-0 172-1 GObject-based wrapper library for libudev
ii  libudev0 172-1 libudev shared library
ii  udev 172-1 /dev/ and hotplug management daemon

krestyaninov@xxx# dpkg -l |grep base-files
ii  base-files 6.5 Debian base system miscellaneous files

krestyaninov@xxx# dpkg -l |grep xorg
ii  xorg 1:7.6+8 X.Org X Window System
...
ii  xserver-xorg  1:7.6+8 X.Org X server
```

Comment: You can run through the setup again and see if that helps.
    dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg

Comment: Which video driver (xserver-xorg-video-what) and input drivers (xserver-xorg-input-what) are you using?  Also, if you can't type or move the mouse, how do you know that the video card isn't locked up? (can you see a clock ticking or something?  ssh in and kill X?)

Comment: 2 egorgry: I tried, but it didn't help me

Comment: 2 DerfK: I see mouse cursor animation and clock ticking. So, it is not problem of video driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that X server don't use udev devices and subtle hinted me on it in log:

```
(II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
```

So, when I pay my attention on these lines and add

```
Section "ServerFlags"
    Option "AutoAddDevices" "False"
EndSection
```

to /etc/X11/xorg.conf problem was solved!

P.S.
Thanks to [Kubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.kubuntu.org/X/InputConfiguration) for info about KDE intput system! :)